# sumar el valor de los elementos de la lista

Tags: python

Estoy practicando un ejercicio en Python para sumar los elementos de una lista y cuando sumo los valores me sale así por consola:

```
 [1, 2]
 1
 3
 [5, 4, 2]
 5
 9
 11
 [12, 11, 120]
 12
 23
 143
 [50, 22, 88, 80, 108]
```

y yo quiero que me salga el valor total de cada lista y como verán me repite siempre el primer elemento en cada resultado:

```
 [1, 2]
 1  <--- aca me agrega el 1 en consola 
 3  <--y yo lo que quiero es que solo me salga la suma que es 3 
 [5, 4, 2]
 5
 9
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

después quiero sumar el valor total de todos los elementos por eso lo fui agregando con `lista2.append(suma)` pero al agregarme mal los valores no puedo hacer bien el valor total de las sumas.

Comment: Hola Alejandro, debes siempre agregar el código como texto no en una imagen, eso dificulta la reproducción y la visualización del mismo y no se indexa para futuras búsquedas. Para formatear el código solo tienes que copiarlo y pegarlo, seleccionar todo el código recien pegado y pulsar `Ctrl` + `k` o el botón `{}` del editor.

Comment: En cuanto a tu problema, el `print` a de estar fuera del `for` no dentro o irá imprimiendo en cada iteración la suma parcial.

Answer (score 3):

Para sumar todo puedes utilizar la función `sum()`, puedes leer sobre ella en la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#sum) de `Python`.

Entonces:

```
lista1 = [ [1, 2], [5, 4, 2], [12, 11, 120] ]
for l in lista1:
    print(sum(l))
```

Suerte

Answer (score 2):

El problema lo tienes en el tabulador del print pero podriass hacerlo de manera sencilla sumando la lista y luego sumando la lista aplanada.

```
lista = [[1,2], [5,4,2], [12,11,120], [50,22, 88,80,108]]
for l in lista:
    print(l)  # <-- imprime la sublista
    print(sum(l)) # <-- la suma de la sublista

print(sum([elem for sublista in lista for elem in sublista])) # <-- imprime la suma de las listas

[1, 2]
3
[5, 4, 2]
11
[12, 11, 120]
143
[50, 22, 88, 80, 108]
348
505 # <-- la suma de todo
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es en la tabulacion.
solo tienes que sacar fuera del bucle el valor de la variable suma y arriba de el imprimes la lista.

```
lista = [ [1, 2], [5, 4, 2], [12, 11, 120] ]
nume = 0

for i in lista:

    for m in i:
        nume += m
    print(i)    
    print(nume)
```

[image]

La salida del script es esta.

Answer (score 1):

Una función para sumar valores ya sea dentro de un array o Tupla

```
def suma(*num):
    resultado = 0
    for i in num:
        resultado += i
    return resultado

print(suma(1,9))
```

Ahora una te explico brevemente por pasos:

1. Definimos funcion
2. Agregamos *parametros (Para indicarle que no hay una cantidad exacta de parametros que va a recibir).
3. Agregamos la variable contenedora de los resultados y le asignamos 0 para limpiar su contenedor y definirla como un entero.
4. agregamos un ciclo for y le indicamos la variable i (OjO: puede ser cualquier variable), seguido de eso le indicamos por medio de "in" que va a recorrer el argumento o parametro *num codigo final:  for i in num
5. agregamos la variable contenedora result y le asignamos el operador de suma seguido del signo de igual. += me imagino que debes saber que significa (Te lo explico también, le llaman operadores de operaciones (Valga la redundacia).
6. Retornamos el resultado final con la variable asignada en el paso 3.
7. Damos salida por print a la funcion y asignamos los parametros en este caso los valores que queremos que sume.

Gracias por llegar asta acá si quieres dar alguna indicación bienvenido.

Answer (score 0):

cuando a partir de una lista quiero obtener otro elemento producto de la iteracion de los objetos internos de la lista utilizo reduce y map

```
from functools import reduce

lista= [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5,6]]
operacion= lambda a,c: a+c

for suma in map(lambda ls: reduce(operacion, ls), lista):
    print(suma)
```

en este caso existe una funcion sum que puede reemplazar el reduce

```
for suma in map(sum,lista): # sin ()
    print(suma)
```

la teoria de reduce es que es una funcion que recibe de parametro una funcion y un iterable, la funcion parametro debe tener dos argumentos, obviamente el iterable debe contener elementos que tenga sentido operarlos todos uno a uno de forma "acumulativa", como una lista de números que quiero sumar como el ejemplo.

```
def funcion_parametro(acum,elem):
    return foo(acum,elem) ##hacer algo random como por ej. acum + elem

def reduce(funcion_parametro,iterable):
    result=iterable[0]
    for element in iterable[1::]:
        result= funcion_parametro(result,element)
    return result
```

en cambio map es mas simple,recibe una funcion y un iterable y aplica esa funcion a cada elemento devolviendo un iterable con los resultados

```
def map(funcion parametro,iterable):
    return (funcion_parametro(i) for i in iterable)
```

** no hace falta definir map ya viene en python, el codigo es para que puedas analizar su funcionamiento basico, reduce esta en la libreria estandar functools

Answer (score 0):

pudes hacerlo asi:

```
from functools import reduce
lista = [[1,2], [5,4,2], [12,11,120], [50,22, 88,80,108]]
suma = sum(reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, lista))
print(suma)
```

functools.reduce es mas rapido y eficiente tanto para listas largas como cortas